# Why does this variable does not update

Tags: python, for-loop, global-variables

I'm working on a card game. The point is that when the user clicks on two cards, they turn face up. If they're not the same, when they click on the third one, the first two disappear (this has not been implemented yet).

I'm trying to use to variables: **first_card** and **second_card** to keep track of the cards, that have been clicked on. I'm also using a list **"exposed"** to change the values from False to True when the user clicks on a card.

The problem is, that the list is updated, but the variables don't update. I mean, when I click on the second card, the **first_card** has a value of **None**, which is the value I initialized the variable with. Why is this happening?

Anyway, here's the code (it won't work unless you run it in CodeSkulptor):
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_RwBwWy2tSI_2.py

```
# implementation of card game - Memory

import simplegui
import random

deck = range(0, 8)* 2
exposed = [False] * len(deck)
print exposed
w = 50
h = 100
WIDTH = w * 16 + 2
HEIGHT = 102
first_card = 0
second_card = 0

# helper function to initialize globals
def new_game():
    global exposed, state
    random.shuffle(deck)
    exposed = [False] * len(deck)
    state = 0
    print deck
    print exposed


# define event handlers
def mouseclick(pos):
    global state, exposed, first_card, second_card
    first_card = None
    second_card = None

    position = pos[0] // 50
    for index in range(len(deck)):
        if position == index  and exposed[index] != True:
            if state == 0:
                #exposed = [False] * len(deck)
                exposed[position] = True
                first_card = position
                state = 1
            elif state == 1:
                #exposed = [False] * len(deck)
                exposed[index] = True
                second_card = index
                state = 2   
            elif state == 2:
                #exposed = [False] * len(deck)
                exposed[index] = True
                second_card = first_card
                first_card = index
                state = 1

    print state
    print "first card", first_card
    print "second card", second_card
    print exposed

# cards are logically 50x100 pixels in size    
def draw(canvas):
    line = 1
    x = 1
    y = 1
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        if exposed[i] == True:
            canvas.draw_text(str(deck[i]), [(0.3* w) + w * i, (y + h) * 0.66], 40, "Black")
        else:
            canvas.draw_polygon([[x, y], [x + w, y], [x + w, y + h], [x, y + h]], line, "White", '#55aa55')
        x += w



# create frame and add a button and labels
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Memory", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
frame.add_button("Reset", new_game)
label = frame.add_label("Turns = " )
frame.set_canvas_background("White")
# register event handlers
frame.set_mouseclick_handler(mouseclick)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# get things rolling
new_game()
frame.start()
```

Comment: Because you always set them to None at the beginning of the mouseclick function, surely.

Comment: *"it won't work unless you run it in CodeSkulptor"* - why not? Can you make a [mcve] that does?

Comment: You dont need the simplegui lib, that code is so easily to debug its painful emabarassing you guys are downvoting him, just add some random tuple pos value to the mouseclick method and help him

Comment: I don't understand why downvoting the question, he's clearly has put some effort on his code and the code is perfectly [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you just need to install that library. IMHO i'd substract reputation from those who's downvoted the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the global state variable, that code is crashing and probably it isnt updating the first_card value

```
import random

state = 0
deck = range(0, 8)* 2
exposed = [False] * len(deck)
print exposed
w = 50
h = 100
WIDTH = w * 16 + 2
HEIGHT = 102
first_card = 0
second_card = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not true your statement of `it won't work unless you run it in CodeSkulptor`, you can find simplegui on pip and everybody can run your code without using CodeSkulptor. I'm wondering what's the reason for getting downvotes, so don't get bothered by them.

Now, about your bug... Let's think about the mouseclick logic, let's assume first_card and second_card are both hide (value=-1) at the beginning of the game. And let's think about a simple game's logic where there are 2 possible states:

- State0, both cards hide: If you click on a card you expose card1
- State1, when first card is exposed: If you click on a card, you need to check whether this new exposed card is equal to the first card, if it's so, the Player has guessed alright so you should return to state0 and keeping exposed both cards. If not, the Player has missed, so you shouldn't expose card2 and hide card1. In this state you could also record how many attempts the player has tried.

You're assigning None `first_card = None` and `second_card = None` over and over, and that's not correct.

Try to give it another shot following these hints and if you're still struggling I'll post you a possible solution.